# failed to deploy rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy my rails app to heroku but but the following message in my heroku log:

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add`gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)

this is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
gem 'puma', '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier', '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.7.0'
gem 'rails-ujs'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug', '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen', '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring', '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :production do 
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end
```

I've tried using the specific version of sqlite3 and the general one that uses the most recent version and neither one works.

Comment: have try to bundle after changing gemfile? because. database.yml is not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have mentioned `sqlite` as database adapter for production. If this is the case, you have to change it to `postgresql`. In `config/database.yml`, change the adapter from

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
```

to

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will cause `postgresql` to be used in `development` and `test` as well. Personally, I think that's a good idea. However, you may want to advise the OP that they will need to install and configure `pg` on their local machine in order to follow your advice.

Comment: @jvillian just moving the adapter from default to their respective environment blocks will allow the separation.

Comment: I agree. But, that's not how you have it now.

Comment: thanks! i actually kept sqlite3 in development but changed the adapter to postqresql in production and that did the trick. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

goodjobbin85, it means, you need to move `gem 'sqlite3'` from `group :development, :test` to `group :development`

if it fails in new deploy, try remove Gemfile.lock, do new `bundle` and `git add/commit/push`

Comment: As stated in the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3), it is not possible to use `sqlite3` on Heroku.

Comment: sure, I've posted quick and dirty solution

Comment: But, it's not a solution. Heroku can't use `sqlite3`. So, moving the gem to `group :development` will not work.

Comment: Heroku use `postgresql` as database by default.  

In Gemfile `group :production` is `gem 'pg` and it will work on heroku

Comment: My sincere apologies. When I first read your answer, I thought you were saying to move gem `sqlite3` to `group :production`. I misread and that was *my fault*. However, the problem is not with the location with the gem, but with the specification of the database adapter (as reflected in the Heroku error).